# Average values of certain keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, input, key

I have a program that allows user to input the yield and speed of a torpedo:

```
#asking user for number of torpedos
count = int(input("Enter in number of functional torpedos: "))
#creating empty dictionary
torpedos = {}
#iterating through dictionary
for i in range(0,count):
  #user choses names of torpedos
  name = input("Enter in torpedo name: ")
  torpedos[name] = {}
  #user input values
  torpedos[name]["Yield"] = int(input("Enter in yield: "))
  torpedos[name]["Speed"] = int(input("Enter in speed: "))
  torpedos[name]["Side"] = input("Enter in side of ship: ")
print(torpedos)
```

I was wondering how I would be able to calculate the average yield and speed of the torpedo's?
I am fairly new to working with dictionaries and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sum(v["Yield"] for v in torpedos.values()) / len(torpedos)`, same for `"Speed"`

Answer (score 0):

To calculate average yield and speed you can use [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) module:

```py
from statistics import mean

# asking user for number of torpedos
count = int(input("Enter in number of functional torpedos: "))
# creating empty dictionary
torpedos = {}
# iterating through dictionary
for i in range(0, count):
    # user choses names of torpedos
    name = input("Enter in torpedo name: ")
    torpedos[name] = {}
    # user input values
    torpedos[name]["Yield"] = int(input("Enter in yield: "))
    torpedos[name]["Speed"] = int(input("Enter in speed: "))
    torpedos[name]["Side"] = input("Enter in side of ship: ")

# compute average yield, speed:
average_yield = mean(v["Yield"] for v in torpedos.values())
average_speed = mean(v["Speed"] for v in torpedos.values())

print(torpedos)
print("Average yield:", average_yield)
print("Average speed:", average_speed)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Enter in number of functional torpedos: 2
Enter in torpedo name: A
Enter in yield: 10
Enter in speed: 20
Enter in side of ship: L
Enter in torpedo name: B
Enter in yield: 15
Enter in speed: 25
Enter in side of ship: R
{'A': {'Yield': 10, 'Speed': 20, 'Side': 'L'}, 'B': {'Yield': 15, 'Speed': 25, 'Side': 'R'}}
Average yield: 12.5
Average speed: 22.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for that :

```
yield_average = sum(v["Yield"] for v in torpedos.values()) / len(torpedos)
speed_average = sum(v["Speed"] for v in torpedos.values()) / len(torpedos)
```